# How can I override the properties in partial class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4, entity

I am developing a MVC application, I have used EF 4.0 while developing it. I have created the classes from the model. Now, I want to add more class for each class made by MVC.

ex. In below code, I get the class Location. **Now, I want to create one more class(Partial class) How can I override properties in partial class ?**

How to do that ?

```
namespace Entities
{
   public partial class Location
   {               
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Remark { get; set; }      
       public string State { get; set; }       
       public string Region { get; set; }
       public string PinCode { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
   }    
}
```

Comment: What dou you mean by "overriding properties in partial class"?

Comment: I want to put some validation on properties in partial class. For ex. I wan to add following code in partial class   '[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Region can accept maximum 50 characters.")]        public string Region { get; set; }'

Comment: Why you cannot put in your current class?

Comment: well, if I write it in current class and If I generate the classes from model again then class get overwrites and all validations get lost. and my structure is not stable yet. so its better to write it in partial class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do attribute decoration in a partial class with an interface

If you have generated the following class (via whatever custom tool)

```
public partial class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

You can add annotations to properties in the generated class (without modifying the generated file) by creating a new interface and a new partial class as below

```
    public interface ILocation
    {
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Region can accept maximum 50 characters.")]
        string Region { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Location :ILocation
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but where can I write this code ? In which class ? In partial class (new one ) ? I am not supposed to add anything in generated class , because it will generated many times until my structure doesn't get fixed.

Comment: @nilesh1foru ive updated my answer to apply to your specific case

Comment: Thanks again, but can I write the above code as it is in new class ? (New partial class , new code file  ?)

Comment: If you have the first partial class you can add an attribute to an existing property by creating the second two classes inside the same DLL

Comment: I think you are not getting what I want... 1. I am using MVC application. 2. I have created model and generated the class by right clicking on 'Generate Class' menu. 3. when I did this different classes are made as per entities in model. 4. now I have a simple question,  can I add new file(Class file) which contains the partial class of any of the class generated by MVC app.(ex. Location class)  and where I can put the DataAnnotations?

Comment: So you have generated a partial location, all you need to do is create the interface and second class ive listed and your generated location class will be annotated with the stringlength annotation

Comment: A partial class allows you to define a class across 2 seperate files (so long as they are in the same assembly) if you attach an interface to either of the partials it will apply to the whole resultant class

Comment: Not getting what you want to say, The code given above is auto generated from MVC(Using generate class utility) Can you please tell What exactly I suppose to write in new files partial class ? I am not going edit above class code, what exactly I supposed to write in new class file ?

Comment: you are telling me to add the interface in the same file/ generated file isn't it ?

Comment: no im telling you to add the interface and new partial class in a brand new file inside the same assembly

Comment: I am keep saying that , when I generate the classes using 'Generate Class' procedure all the files are get cleaned and get written by class generator again. ( I genrate the classed daily, till my structure wont get fixed).So I want to create partial class which will be in new file and will contain override properties of above class, so though above class rewritten my second class file will untouched.

Comment: i cant work out how to explain this to you any differently put the bottom two things in a brand new file and when you generate your origional it will keep the attribute

Comment: Please check my new answer, I am giving the code of two class files.

Comment: this won't work for validation because it will be overrided at generated code block, and annotations will be too. This mean no annotations in your interface take effect

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is validation, you can use so-called metadata types.

Detailed tutorial is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx).