# Parse between poco in Unity3D and EF6 entity

Tags: entity-framework, unity-game-engine

I am parsing an object from a web service to a Unity3d application. However i cannot reference one library with all my classes in it for both programs as Unity only accepts dlls built using .Net 3.5.
This means the EF6 library that my entities use, cause Unity to spit errors.

I can remove all my references to EF6 and it will work fine as POCO's, but then i have to keep a (practically identical) separate library for the EF6 stuff to work - not good OOP!
I thought i could use a POCO as a base object and create entities that inherit from this and implement extra EF properties, such as their Id key, but EF6 doesn't seem to allow this.

So the way i see it is i either maintain two almost identical class libraries or i find an ORM version old enough that Unity supports it... and probably end up re-writing the back end program in the process.
Are there any other ways to solve this issue?

Comment: Partial classes offer a partial solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807517/how-can-i-override-the-properties-in-partial-class 
Unfortunately you cannot split partial classes between two assemblies so the next step is to auto compile them into their own dll when the main library is built, but that should be a relatively clean and easy solution... Lets hope i have not spoken too soon about the 'easy' part! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial classes offer a partial solution - stackoverflow.com/questions/11807517/… Unfortunately you cannot split partial classes between two assemblies so the next step is to auto compile them into their own dll when the main library is built, but that should be a relatively clean and easy solution... Lets hope i have not spoken too soon about the 'easy' part! ;)