# Value cannot be null Linq to XML

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have a Customer class and use an XML response to fill the class with some data as below (ns is Namespace)

```
Dim GetCustomers = From c As XElement In XDoc.Descendants(ns + "customer")
              Select New Customer With {.Name = c.Element(ns + "name"),
                                        .Gender = CStr(c.Element(ns + "gender")),
                                        .EndDate = CStr(c.Element(ns + "SubscriptionEndData"))}
```

The line that has an error is EndDate which is of a Datetime type in the database.... The error is "Message = "Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: element"". To test my theory i changed the type from dateTime to Nvarchar and the code works.

How could i overcome this issue with leaving the EndDate type as datetime? I dont really want to change it to a NVARCHAR in the database as later i would like to do some calculations with the date. I tried using anonymous types with the Key keyword but that didnt work, therefore after searching around and playing around i cant add an if statement above so i guess there must be another way which i may not be aware of? Sorry pretty new to Linq to XML and anonymous types so appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

EDIT: After adding partial class

Reading this thread [How can I override the properties in partial class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807517/how-can-i-override-the-properties-in-partial-class) i created the below class/Interface

```
Public Interface ICustomer
    Property EndDate As Nullable(Of DateTime)
End Interface

Partial Public Class Customer
    Implements ICustomer


    Public Property EndDate1 As Date? Implements ICustomer.EndDate
End Class
```

Comment: Use a regular For loop and check each `SubscriptionEndData` for null before calling it.

Comment: If it's datetime in the DB, it should be `Nullable(Of DateTime)` in .NET, because SQL can contain NULLs, .NET cannot - for value types (which DateTime is). It should not work with nvarchar in all cases, because now you made it culture dependent. To prevent this and many other issues, always use `Option Strict On` in your code. It won't magically solve anything, but at least will keep you aware of what's going on.

Comment: OneFineDay - I will use that as a last resort as i think im missing something here. Neolisk - that makes sense. I added a partial class (see edited code above) however it adds a 1 against the property i want to use which but even using that property i still couldnt get it to work