# Changing the entity framework templates

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

I have some problems while using Entity Framework.

I always use a JSONHelper class to convert a list of string to JSON.

Here is the JSONHelper Class:

```
public static class JSONHelper
{
    public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }

    public static string ToJSON(this object obj, int recursionDepth)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth;
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }
}
```

This class creates JSON. But sometimes it gives me an error saying that "A circular reference was detected in Entity..........."

So in some of the properties of the classes that entity-framework created for me, I have to use `[ScriptIgnore]` Attribute. Then it works fine.

Now, let's say I made a small change in database. So I will refresh my ADO.Net Entity Data Model. Then I again have to open all those class files and write [ScriptIgnore].

So, I decided to make a change in template designer. But I could not find the files that entity framework uses to create my POCO classes.

Any Ideas????

Please don't tell me to change the way of converting List to JSON.

Comment: Well, since you don't want to change the way you are converting the object to JSON, you have a lot of work ahead of you. Or you can just change to the Newtonsoft JSON serializer that has all the functionality already built to handle circular references without having to twiddle with your EF classes. Up to you. Good luck.

Comment: @NickZimmerman For your kind information. I have just now tried NewtonSoft.Json. I also gives me error as stated : Self referencing loop detected for property .............

Comment: there is an option on the NewtonSoft.Json that will handle that SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

Comment: @NickZimmerman how do I use that option? I mean where should I write the above mentioned code?

Comment: @NickZimmerman THANKS for mentioning that. I got it. You can post it as answer.

Comment: posted. And you are welcome. The NewtonSoft.Json serializer is the de facto standard. And plenty of documentation and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use the NewtonSoft.Json serializer. It works very well and has settings options for handling many things, including circular references. There is a lot of good documentation and help available for that serializer. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Circular references are controlled like this:

```
SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807517/how-can-i-override-the-properties-in-partial-class) answer describes what you need to do.

For any entity which you need to apply the `ScriptIgnore` attribute, you can make a partial class which does the attribute decoration.

Say your entity is like this

```
public partial class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a separate partial class like this

```
public interface IEntity
    {
        [ScriptIgnore]
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Entity:IEntity
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by modifying the T4 template file (.tt file). Take a look at the .tt file in a text editor and you will be able to see where your properties are being created. Insert the [ScriptIgnore] attribute in your template and it will be automatically included when you re-generate your entities.

You might need to include an appropriate 'using' at the top of the template etc.

You can do a lot by editing the T4 template, we used it to automatically have our entities implement INotifyPropertyChanged for all properties.

Comment: Can you provide me the location of .tt file??

Comment: I am not at the machine that has the code in question but the .tt file should be wherever the target is for your generated entities. It shows in Visual Studio as an expandable node that when expanded shows the generated entities. You can right-click on that expandable node and say 'open in text editor' or similar.

Comment: Here is a link to an post (not mine) that shows the location of the .tt files. We generate our entities to a location different than the default, but if you are using the default location the .tt file will be under your .edmx node. http://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=JMP3ZKUNkGvnwM&tbnid=L2Dx0L_4twTXTM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fromiller.com%2F2013%2F05%2F15%2Frunning-ef-t4-code-generation-templates-from-command-line%2F&ei=-WH3U8DBJ4qcygTQ54I4&bvm=bv.73373277,d.aWw&psig=AFQjCNFDFY8LP8kZnXh7KMb54Yx1Ha04-w&ust=1408807799605811